# How much ram i need in cloud hosting for 100 kb website storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have one website that has simple one page that fetches trending videos from youtube with the use of youtube api and size of the website is just 100 kb. website is created by using of HTML,CSS,PHP.  I want to host it on any good cloud hosting. Suppose i will get 10000 daily visitors to my website then **1gb ram and 1 coreCPU is sufficient for that?**

Answer (score 0):

**Nobody can answer this question for you** because every application is different, and much of it depends on the patterns of your particular user base.

The only way to know the requirements is to **deploy the system and then simulate user traffic**. Monitor the system to identify stress points, which could be RAM, CPU or Network. You can then adjust the size of the instance accordingly, and even change Instance Type to obtain a different mix of RAM and CPU.

Alternatively, just deploy *something* and monitor it closely. Then, adjust things based on usage patterns you see. This is "**testing in production**".

You could also consider using **Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling**, which can automatically launch new instances to handle an increased load. This way, the resources vary based on usage. However, this design would require a Load Balancer in front of the instances.

Then, if you want to get really fancy, you could simply host a static web page from Amazon S3 and have the page **make API calls to a backend hosted in AWS Lambda**. The Lambda function will **automatically scale** by running multiple functions in parallel. This way, you do not require any Amazon EC2 instances and you only pay for resources when somebody actually uses the website. It would be the cheapest architecture to run. However, you would need to rewrite your web page and back-end code to fit this architecture.